# windows task scheduler works with one $principal but not the other

Tags: windows, tasks

This is weird, im creating task schedule on windows server 2012 r2. this is a simple task to run a powershell script. this is the $principal
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -GroupID "BUILTIN\Administrators" -RunLevel Highest
scripts then works with one problem:

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWL0V.png)

it sais it will run only when user is logged on. i want it to run anyway even if no one is logged on.
so i googled and found this:
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
in this case i do get the "desired option"
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMiEq.png)

only this time. the script wont run at all.
how can i achive this goal which is to make the script run anyway when computer is on even if no one is logged in

Comment: Are you sure the script doesn't run at all? Or is it simply not performing the actions correctly? Keep in mind that if the script runs as SYSTEM user, many features will be missing, such as network access. If your script relies upon doing something on a network share, this will fail. Similarly, if you run the script with highest privileges with a network user, you need to manually create network mappings in your script.

Comment: the script does need to invoke command to remote computer but it uses stored credentials for that issue, im positive the script doesnt run at all

Comment: Make the script write to a log file locally to make sure. I too had a problem like this once and I was so sure the script was not running at all. In the end it did run but I ran into a restriction issue. Once I wrote to a logfile, I could see where in the script things went haywire and figured out where to fix it.

Comment: you are right, the script does run, thank you!